# SQL - Average on DateDiff with taking out weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL statement that calculates how many days late our vendors pay for invoices.  It only includes weekdays and it works perfectly.  My customer is now asking if I can have an average of those days late per vendor.  Here is my code that works:

```
DATEDIFF(dd, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE))
-(DATEDIFF(wk, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE)) * 2)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV) = 'Sunday'
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE)) = 'Saturday'
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END) AS 'DAYS LATE'
```

If I try to put this in an `AVG()`, but it tells me I cannot perform an aggregate function on an aggregate function.

UPDATE:

This is my original SQL:

```
SELECT
    PURCHTABLE.PURCHNAME AS 'VENDOR NAME', 
    PURCHTABLE.ORDERACCOUNT AS 'VENDOR NUMBER',
    COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHTABLE.PURCHID) AS 'PURCHASE ORDER', 
    COUNT(PURCHLINE.LINENUMBER) AS 'NUMBER OF LINES', 
    SUM(PURCHLINE.LINEAMOUNT) AS 'PO PRICE TOTAL',
    DATEDIFF(dd, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE))-(DATEDIFF(wk, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE)) * 2)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE)) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DAYS LATE'
FROM
PURCHTABLE
JOIN 
PURCHLINE ON PURCHLINE.PURCHID = PURCHTABLE.PURCHID
JOIN
VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR ON VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.PURCHID = PURCHTABLE.PURCHID
WHERE
PURCHTABLE.DELIVERYDATE >= '2017-01-01'
AND
PURCHTABLE.DELIVERYDATE <= '2017-01-20'
AND
PURCHTABLE.ORDERACCOUNT = 'VN03526'
GROUP BY  
PURCHTABLE.PURCHNAME, 
PURCHTABLE.ORDERACCOUNT,
PURCHTABLE.DELIVERYDATE,
PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV
```

So I don't quite understand how I change that to what you are saying.....I'm tried this but it's not working.

```
SELECT 
    PURCHTABLE.PURCHNAME AS 'VENDOR NAME', 
    PURCHTABLE.ORDERACCOUNT AS 'VENDOR NUMBER'
FROM
    (SELECT
        PURCHTABLE.PURCHNAME AS 'VENDOR NAME', 
        PURCHTABLE.ORDERACCOUNT AS 'VENDOR NUMBER',
        COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHTABLE.PURCHID) AS 'PURCHASE ORDER', 
        COUNT(PURCHLINE.LINENUMBER) AS 'NUMBER OF LINES', 
        SUM(PURCHLINE.LINEAMOUNT) AS 'PO PRICE TOTAL',
        DATEDIFF(dd, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE))-(DATEDIFF(wk, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE)) * 2)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MAX(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE)) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DAYS LATE'
    FROM
    PURCHTABLE
    JOIN 
    PURCHLINE ON PURCHLINE.PURCHID = PURCHTABLE.PURCHID
    JOIN
    VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR ON VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.PURCHID = PURCHTABLE.PURCHID
    WHERE
    PURCHTABLE.DELIVERYDATE >= '2017-01-01'
    AND
    PURCHTABLE.DELIVERYDATE <= '2017-01-20'
    AND
    PURCHTABLE.ORDERACCOUNT = 'VN03526') A
GROUP BY  
PURCHTABLE.PURCHNAME, 
PURCHTABLE.ORDERACCOUNT,
PURCHTABLE.DELIVERYDATE,
PURCHTABLE.CONFIRMEDDLV
```

Comment: try sub query select avg([DAYS LATE]) FROM (your query) as t

Comment: Wrap it  with one more `select .. group by`

Answer (score 1):

The code you have at the moment will be part of a larger query, such as:

```
select VendorID
      ,VendorName
      ...
      ...
      ,<Your Days Late Code> as DaysLate
      ,InvoiceAmount
      ...
from tables
group by VendorID
      ,VendorName
```

all you need to do to average over all of this is pick the other columns you want to do the average by and wrap the whole thing in another `select` statement:

```
select VendorID
      ,VendorName
      ,avg(DaysLate) as AverageDaysLate
      ,sum(InvoiceAmount) as TotalInvoiceAmount
from(
    select VendorID
          ,VendorName
          ...
          ...
          ,<Your Days Late Code> as DaysLate
          ,InvoiceAmount
          ...
    from tables
    group by VendorID
            ,VendorName
) a
group by VendorID
        ,VendorName
```

Comment: iamdave, are you able to come back to see my updated code and help?

Comment: @Rage  I don't understand why you have made the changes you have made?  You appear to be adding things at random without giving them any thought as to what they are doing and why.  Why have you left the `group by` from your original query outside the sub select?  Why haven't you added any aggregation on columns like `DaysLate` in your top level `select`?  Just wrap the whole thing in a sub select, `select` all the columns with an `avg` on `DaysLate` and `group by` the rest.

Comment: I was just trying to get it working first which it is not.  I will try to do what you said and get back to you.....